# Check performance of a file upload but don't execute function powershell

Tags: powershell

This is a two part question I suppose. I have code as follows :

```
Try{
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll'
}

catch {
    Throw "Unable to load SharePoint Client runtime"
}

Function DryRun-UploadFile($DestinationFolder, $File, $FileSource)
{


    if($FileSource -eq $null){
        $FileSource = $Folder
    }
    $path= [String]$FileSource+'\'+$File
    $Size = get-item $Path
    $Size = $Size.length

    if($Size -lt 160000){
        if($path -like '*.doc*' -Or $path -like '*.xls*' -Or $path -like '*.ppt*'){
        ##Get authors of document
            if($path -like '*.doc*'){
                $application = New-Object -ComObject word.application
                $application.Visible = $false
                $document = $application.documents.open($path)
            }
            if($path -like '*.xls*'){
                $application = New-Object -ComObject Excel.application
                $application.Visible = $false
                $document = $application.workbooks.open($path)
            }   
            if($path -like '*.ppt*'){
                $application = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
                $application.Visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
                $document = $application.presentations.open($path)
            }   


            $binding = "System.Reflection.BindingFlags" -as [type]
            $properties = $document.BuiltInDocumentProperties
            foreach($property in $properties)
            {
                $pn = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("name",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null)

                trap [system.exception]
                {

                    continue
                }
                if ($pn -eq "Last author") {
                    $lastSaved = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("value",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null)
                    $lastSaved = [String]$lastSaved

                }
                if ($pn -eq "author") {
                    $author = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("value",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null)
                    $author = [String]$author
                }

    }

    $document.Close()
    $application.quit()
    if($path -like '*.ppt*'){
        $application = $null
        [gc]::collect()
        [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        Stop-Process –name powerpnt 
    }
    ##set author if null returned
    if($lastSaved -eq ''){
        $lastSaved = "Rob Ireland"
    }
    if($author -eq ''){
        $author = "Rob Ireland"
    }

    $author =$Context.Web.EnsureUser($author)
    $lastSaved = $Context.Web.EnsureUser($lastSaved)
    }else{

        $CreationOwner =Get-Acl $path | Select-Object Owner
        #$lastSaved = "Rob Ireland"
        #$author = "Rob Ireland"

    }
    ##Get created date
    $CreationDate = Get-ItemProperty -Path $FileSource\$File | Select-Object CreationTime
    $CreateDT =  [string]$CreationDate.CreationTime
    $revDate,$Time = $CreateDT.Split(" ",2)
    $arr = $revDate -split '/'
    $revDate = $arr[2]+'-'+$arr[0]+'-'+$arr[1]
    $DateSP = $revDate+'T'+$Time

    ##Get Modified date
    $ModifiedDate = Get-ItemProperty -Path $FileSource\$File | Select-Object LastWriteTime
    $ModDT =  [string]$ModifiedDate.LastWriteTime
    $ModDate,$ModTime = $ModDT.Split(" ",2)
    $Modarr = $ModDate -split '/'   
    $ModDate = $Modarr[2]+'-'+$Modarr[0]+'-'+$Modarr[1] 
    $ModDateSP = $ModDate+'T'+$ModTime


    $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
    $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
    $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
    $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
    $FileCreationInfo.URL = $File
    $Upload = $DestinationFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
    $Context.Load($Upload)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    $ListItem = $Upload.ListItemAllFields;

    $Listitem["Modified"] = $ModDateSP

    $Listitem["Created"] = $DateSP
    $Listitem["Author"] = $author  
    $Listitem["Editor"] = $lastSaved  

    $ListItem.Update()
    $Context.Load($Upload)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    }else{
    $global:Count=$global:Count+1

    }
}

function DryRun-PopulateFolder($ListRootFolder, $FolderRelativePath, $Count)
{
    #split the FolderRelativePath passed into chunks (between the backslashes) so that we can check if the folder structure exists
    $PathChunks = $FolderRelativePath.substring(1).split("\")

    #Make sure we start with a fresh WorkingFolder for every folder passed to the function
    if($WorkingFolder)
    {
        Remove-Variable WorkingFolder
    }

    #Start with the root folder of the list, load this into context
    $WorkingFolder = $ListRootFolder
    $Context.load($WorkingFolder)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    #Load the folders of the current working folder into context
    $Context.load(($WorkingFolder.folders))
    $Context.executeQuery()

    #Set the FileSource folder equal to the absolute path of the folder that passed to the function
    $FileSource = $Folder + $FolderRelativePath

    #Loop through the folder chunks, ensuring that the correct folder hierarchy exists in the destination
    foreach($Chunk in $PathChunks)
    {
        #Check to find out if a subfolder exists in the current folder that matches the patch chunk being evaluated
        if($WorkingFolder.folders | ? {$_.name -eq $Chunk})
        {
            #Log the status to the PowerShell host window


            #Since we will be evaluating other chunks in the path, set the working folder to the current folder and load this into context.
            $WorkingFolder = $WorkingFolder.folders | ? {$_.name -eq $Chunk}
            $Context.load($WorkingFolder)
            $Context.load($WorkingFolder.folders)
            $Context.ExecuteQuery()

        }
        else
        {
            #If the folder doesn't exist, Log a message indicating that the folder doesn't exist, and another message indicating that it is being created


            #Load the working folder into context and create a subfolder with a name equal to the chunk being evaluated, and load this into context
            $Context.load($WorkingFolder)
            $Context.load($WorkingFolder.folders)
            $Context.ExecuteQuery()
            $WorkingFolder= $WorkingFolder.folders.add($Chunk)
            $Context.load($WorkingFolder)
            $Context.load($WorkingFolder.folders)
            $Context.ExecuteQuery()


        }

    }

    #Folder is confirmed existing or created - now it's time to list all files in the source folder, and assign this to a variable
    $FilesInFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSource | ? {$_.psIsContainer -eq $False}

    #For each file in the source folder being evaluated, call the UploadFile function to upload the file to the appropriate location
    Foreach ($File in ($FilesInFolder))
    {

        #Notify the operator that the file is being uploaed to a specific location

        if(!($File -like '*.txt')){

        #Upload the file
        DryRun-UploadFile $WorkingFolder $File $FileSource 
        }else{
            $global:Count=$global:Count+1

        }

    }



}


Function DryRun-Copy-Files{

    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$User,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Folder,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$DocLibName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials,


    )





    try{
        #Bind to site collection
        $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)

    }catch{                          
                Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
                Write-Host "No further parts of the migration will be completed, The script will now exit" 
                Exit
        }
                $pass =  ConvertTo-SecureString $credentials.Password -AsPlainText -Force
                $Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credentials.UserName,$pass)
        $Context.Credentials = $Creds
    #Retrieve list
    $List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocLibName)
    $Context.Load($List)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    #Get a recursive list of all folders beneath the folder supplied by the operator
    $AllFolders = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $Folder |? {$_.psIsContainer -eq $True}

    #Get a list of all files that exist directly at the root of the folder supplied by the operator
    $FilesInRoot = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder | ? {$_.psIsContainer -eq $False}

    #Upload all files in the root of the folder supplied by the operator
    Foreach ($File in ($FilesInRoot))
    {


        if(!($File -like '*.txt')){
        #Upload the file
        DryRun-UploadFile($list.RootFolder) $File
        }else{
             $global:Count=$global:Count+1

        }



    }

    #Loop through all folders (recursive) that exist within the folder supplied by the operator
    foreach($CurrentFolder in $AllFolders)
    {
        #Set the FolderRelativePath by removing the path of the folder supplied by the operator from the fullname of the folder
        $FolderRelativePath = ($CurrentFolder.FullName).Substring($Folder.Length)

        #Call the PopulateFolder function for the current folder, which will ensure that the folder exists and upload all files in the folder to the appropriate location
        DryRun-PopulateFolder ($list.RootFolder) $FolderRelativePath



    }

Write-output "Number of files excluded is: "$global:Count | Out-file DryRun.txt 




}
```

This file uploads a file structure to sharepoint online. this works fine I just want to add to it. Firstly is there anyway to check the performance of the upload so check how many MB/S the files are being uploaded by. Secondly How can I turn this into a dry/practice run so it doesn't actually do the upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the file size so time your upload using Measure-Command or [Diagnostics.StopWatch]. You can do the math from there.

PowerShell advanced cmdlets enable you to use the -WhatIf param. You will need to add [cmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)] immediately below your function. You can then wrap actions in an if like this:

```
if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($foo)) {
    Get-Item $foo
}
```

To perform a dry run just execute the function with the -whatIf param.
Alternatively you can maintain another script and just Write-Host your executions. I'd advise investing the time with advanced functions though.